# OSX: NSTableView cells with multiple lines?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

What's the best way to have `NSTableView` cells with multiple lines ? Let's say 5 or 6 ?

I am aware of this question and the answer  "[iOS: UITableView cells with multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964448/ios-uitableview-cells-with-multiple-lines)" but the mechanism seems to be different on `OSX`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're having? If you use a view-based NSTableView, you can make a NSTableCellViews with arbitrary arrangements of any kind of subviews you like in Interface Builder, very similarly to what you can do on iOS. That includes multi-line text fields, or multiple single line text fields arranged in rows.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the pain to use view-based tableviews...

Comment: View-based table views are *much* easier to customize than cell-based table views. You're not avoiding pain by using a cell-based table view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer [View-based NSTableView with rows that have dynamic heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights) :

In the delegate of your `NSTableView` :

```
@interface MenuDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArrayController * theArrayController ;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTextFieldCell * anExtraTextFieldCell ;
@property (nonatomic) NSRect tallRect ;

@end



@implementation  MenuDelegate



#pragma mark - Initialisations


- (id)initwithArrayController:(NSArrayController *)theArrayController;
{
    self = [super init] ;

    if (self)
    {
        self.theArrayController = theArrayController ;

        self.anExtraTextFieldCell = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] init] ;
    }

    return self ;
}



- (CGFloat)     tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
              heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row {

    if (!self.tallRect.size.width)
    {
        NSTableColumn * firstColum = tableView.tableColumns[0] ;
        self.tallRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, firstColum.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    }

    // Access the content of the cell.
    NSString * content = [self.theArrayController.arrangedObjects[row] valueForKey:@"title"] ;
    self.anExtraTextFieldCell.stringValue = content ;

    CGFloat result = [self.anExtraTextFieldCell cellSizeForBounds:self.tallRect].height + 5;


    if (result < [tableView rowHeight])
    {
        result = [tableView rowHeight] ;
    }

    return result ;
}
```